# wordpress - query_post loop for first post

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, wordpress-theming

I am using `query_post` to show a list of recent post.
And I want to give special style and html markup to the first post.

This is my current code:

```
 $cat_args=array(
              'orderby' => 'name',
              'order' => 'ASC'
               );
            $categories=get_categories($cat_args);
              foreach($categories as $category) {
                $args=array(
                  'showposts' => -1,
                  'category__in' => array($category->term_id),
                  'caller_get_posts'=>1
                );
                $posts=query_posts($args);
                  if ($posts) {
                    echo '<h3><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> </h3> ';                   

                    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
                        if( $wp_query->current_post == 0 ) :?>
                            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="thumb" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" ><?php the_post_thumbnail('post-thumb'); ?></a>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <h5><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>
                        <?php else : ?>
                            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="thumb" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" ><?php the_post_thumbnail('post-thumb'); ?></a>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <h5><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a></h5> 
                        <?php endif;

                    endwhile;
                  } // if ($posts
                } // foreach($categories
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is just wrap your snippet into `if` statement and call `the_post` function before `while` loop. By calling `the_post` function you will fetch first record from your queue. It should be like this:

```
if ( have_posts() ) :
    the_post();

    if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : 
        ?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="thumb" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('post-thumb'); ?>
        </a><?php 
    endif; 
    ?><h5>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        </a>
    </h5><?php


    while ( have_posts() ) : 
        the_post(); 
        if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="thumb" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" ><?php the_post_thumbnail('post-thumb'); ?></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <h5><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a></h5> 
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: MAn, I am sorry for posting partial code, the code which you have provided, I am already using that. I want a loop count for styling first post, like `$count==1 then style for first post`

Comment: @user1983017 read my snippet carefully, i have extracted first post from the loop and you can style it how you want.

Comment: This answer is incomprehensible.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to style [the whole post, the title, whatever], you're going to want to identify the first post, and then conditionally output a class or whatever HTML you want for that post. The "loop" is the part of your code between the while and the endwhile. So right before the loop, put:

```
$is_first_post = TRUE;
```

then inside the while loop, before whatever it is you're trying to add styles to, put:

```
if ($is_first_post == TRUE){
    echo (" .... THIS WOULD BE ADDED TO THE FIRST POST ONLY ....");
    $is_first_post = FALSE; //this flags the next post as not being first 
}
```